# Python Flask ValueError: View function did not return a response

Tags: python, json, flask

This is my Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signal():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.get_json()
        return content
    else:
        return 'Hello, world!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I run this HTTP Post (from the same machine):

```
import requests
import json
dump= '{"on":"true"}'
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000', dump)
```

And receive this error:

```
[2017-03-04 14:18:35,250] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
return self.finalize_request(rv)
File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
response = self.make_response(rv)
File "c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1725, in make_response
raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

Any ideas on why this is occuring? From reading online at first I thought it was because I didn't have an else in case of it being a GET, but I can't understand now.

Comment: Indentation is wrong, or is it just from the copy/pasting?

Comment: It's probably copy paste, but where exactly are you meaning? Under the IF?

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing returning your post request payload directly, you should do `jsonify` and flask has this util function

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signal():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.get_json()
        return jsonify(content)
    else:
        return 'Hello, world!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Then in your testing code, add `Content-Type` into header, (without this, `request.get_json()` won't work):

```
dump = '{"on":"true"}'
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000', data=dump,
                  headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

Comment: This wouldn't trigger the error though.

Comment: @Vallentin It will, because if there's no payload, `content` is a `NoneType`, Flask does not allow `NoneType` as return value

Comment: That is true. However considering the condition of the testing, then `content` shouldn't be a `NoneType`.

Comment: @Vallentin aha, there is a second mistake here. No `Content-Type` specified in the request so `request.get_json() `  won't work

Comment: Ohh nice catch! +1 from me then! :)

Comment: Thanks! Works great! The only thing that slightly confuses me is how to actually display the JSON/ write it to a file. I thought it would display in the cmd, but it does not. I'm probably not understanding Flask, so I'm sorry.

Comment: @AndrewBlair just print them when you want

Comment: @Duan i cannot get this to work.    `r = requests.put("http://192.168.1.102/api/F5La7UpN6XueJZUts1QdyBBbIU8dEvaT1EZs1Ut0/lights/5/state/", jsonify(content))` in the signal() if request method post

Answer (score 0):

Looks like - issue is with your script which is making request to your application.  Try with curl, something like below:

```
$ curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000 -d '{"on":"true"}'
```

You will get response as below:

```
{
  "on": "true"
}
```

Your code (added jsonify) should look as below:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request,jsonify 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signal():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.json
        return jsonify(content)
    else:
        return 'Hello, world!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Should the response be displaying in my terminal?

Comment: Yes!  you are using two terminals. One to your flask application and the other to run curl command.  Curl will respond your JSON object.